# Reg.ex pattern match not working in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have this select query which uses regex which matches a string in a large string content.

Somehow when I run it in pgadmin it does not result in anything. But the same pattern matches the desired when I test in other regex matching tools.

```
select count(DEVICE.DeviceID) from DEVICE 
where ('!   
redundancy   
!   
vlan internal allocation policy ascending   
!' ~* '^redundancy$')
```

I am expecting the pattern to be matched because the string "redundancy" exists in one line.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: The WHERE clause seems rather useless, you can simplify that to `where true` - did you mean to compare that to some column in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the [*newline-sensitive matching*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-MATCHING-RULES):

```
m   historical synonym for n
n   newline-sensitive matching
```

> If newline-sensitive matching is specified, `.` and bracket expressions using `^` will never match the newline character (so that matches will never cross newlines unless the RE explicitly arranges it) and `^` and `$` will match the empty string after and before a newline respectively, in addition to matching at beginning and end of string respectively. But the ARE escapes `\A` and `\Z` continue to match beginning or end of string *only*.

Use either

```
'(?m)^redundancy$'
```

or

```
'(?n)^redundancy$'
```